# Explicitly substitute modulo operation by bitwise?

Tags: java, performance, jit

As far as I know, modulo `%` is a pretty costly operation, backed by division opertation underneath, the slowest operation for CPU.

Whether it worth or not to substitute this operation explicitly by it's bitwise analog `number & (divisor - 1)` in code, or `JIT` can do this for us implicitly?

Comment: Don't worry about these low-level optimizations. In 99.9% of cases they will make no perceptible difference. In the 0.1% of cases (e.g. algo trading) - well firstly I'd question your choice to use Java in the first place - if you were working on applications like that then you probably wouldn't be posing the question. Focus on writing code that is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Run some tests and see what you get.

Comment: You asking about performance or in general?

Comment: @talex performance reasons, code readability is the least thing I'm interested in here

Comment: missing something: `17 % 5 == 2` but `17 & (5-1) == 0`

Comment: `number & (divisor - 1)` is only equivalent to remainder in certain specific cases. If you know that your situation falls into those cases, then you can use it instead. Otherwise, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I aware `JIT` doesn't optimize such expression so:

`number%divisor` is not faster (slower or same speed) than `number & (divisor - 1)` in case of `divisor` is constant (so `divisor - 1` can be calculated in compile time).

It is difficult to say how big difference will be because in modern CPU it will depend on code around it, cache state, and many other factors.

PS: Keep in mind that optimization will work only if `divisor` is power of `2`.